# How to concatenete strings after str_split

Tags: r, paste, strsplit

Given this data frame

```
column_1     column_2
A            w,x
B            z 
C            q,r,s
```

My desired output would be

```
"Aw", "Ax", "Bz", "Cq", "Cr", "Cs"
```

I've tried

```
paste0(df$column_1, strsplit(df$column_2, ","))
```

But the output is

```
"Ac(\"w\", \"x\")"  "Bz"  "Cc(\"q\", \"r\", \"s\")"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split `column_2` on "," and paste them with `column_1` using `mapply`

```
unlist(mapply(paste0, df$column_1,strsplit(df$column_2, ",")))
#[1] "Aw" "Ax" "Bz" "Cq" "Cr" "Cs"
```

Comment: This one is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

We can `rep`licate the 'column_1' by the `lengths` of `list` output from `strsplit` and then do the `paste`

```
 lst1 <- strsplit(df$column_2, ",")
 paste0(rep(df$column_1, lengths(lst1)), unlist(lst1))
 #[1] "Aw" "Ax" "Bz" "Cq" "Cr" "Cs"
```

NOTE: The above is a vectorized approach as we are not looping through the `list`

---

Or use `stack` to create a two column data.frame from `list` and then `paste`

```
 do.call(paste0, stack(setNames(lst1, df$column_1))[2:1])
 #[1] "Aw" "Ax" "Bz" "Cq" "Cr" "Cs"
```

`stack`ing to a two column data.frame approach may be a bit less efficient compared to the first approach

---

Or with `tidyverse`, split the 'column_2' to long format with `separate_rows`, then `unite` the two columns and `pull` it to `vector`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    separate_rows(column_2) %>%
    unite(newcol, column_1, column_2, sep="") %>%
    pull(newcol)
#[1] "Aw" "Ax" "Bz" "Cq" "Cr" "Cs"
```

---

The issue in the OP's approach is based on the fact that the `strsplit` output is a `list` of `vector`s.  We need a function to loop over the `list` (`lapply/sapply/vapply`) or `unlist` the `list` into a `vector` while `replicating the` 'column_1' (to make the `length` during `paste`ing)

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(column_1 = c("A", "B", "C"), column_2 = c("w,x", 
 "z", "q,r,s")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved using below code. Although not very idiomatic

```
df <- data.frame(column_1 = c("A", "B", "C"), column_2 = c("w,x", "z", "q,r,s"))
l_vals <- strsplit(as.character(df$column_2), split = ",", perl =TRUE)
l_append = list()
for(i in seq_along(l_vals)){
  l_append <- c(l_append,paste0(df$column_1[i], l_vals[[i]]))
}

unlist(l_append)
```